# How does one activate "Multi Mode Viewfinder" setting on Fujifilm X-T1?

Tags: fujifilm, evf

The Fujifilm website documents an "Advanced Feature" which it calls "Multi Mode Viewfinder". This allows one to use various viewfinder modes called "Full", "Normal", "Vertical" and "Dual".

Dual is particularly interesting:

> In the viewfinder's "DUAL" mode, you can enjoy a view of the subject unlike anything seen through a traditional optical viewfinder. In Manual Focus, Dual cleverly displays a split screen that lets you see both a regular view of the scene, as well as the Focus Assist view (Focus Peaking and Digital Split Image Focus) at the same time, so focusing is easy and precise.
>
> [image: Dual mode]

Having scoured forums and other sites on the internet, I've been unable to find how to activate this setting. Going through all the various menus on the camera has also not brought anything to light.

**Does anyone know how to turn it on?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page 21 of your [Owners Manual](http://www.2cameraguys.com/pdf/FujiFilm-X-T1-camera-manual.pdf) says “The DISP/BACK button controls the display of indicators in the
viewfinder and LCD monitor”

It also says that Dual Display only works in Manual Focus mode.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the Fuji site doesn't mention how to use this anywhere and googling the relevant terms did not bring up any searchable copy of the manual. Of course when I tried, it didn't work because I wasn't in manual then.